# how to create seperate html element for each comma separated value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i have xml format, which contains array of values like following:

```html
<xml total="446">
    <document>
        <id><![CDATA[binary:181-22559]]></id>
        <language><![CDATA[[Croatian]]]></language>
        <application><![CDATA[]]></application>
    </document>
  <document>
        <id><![CDATA[binary:181-22559]]></id>
        <language><![CDATA[[English]]]></language>
        <application><![CDATA[[Outdoor, LED, Indoor, Signage]]]></application>
   </document>
</xml>
```

i am facing following 2 issues when try to render above xml using xslt:
1.  it is rendering along with square brackets '['
2.  i am not able to create separate html element for comma separated values.

following is my xslt:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
 <xsl:template match="/">
      
      <hr class="grid-hr inner-grid"/>
  <fieldset>
   <legend>%%filter_document_language%%:</legend>
   <label class="visuallyhidden" for="document-language">Language:</label>
   <select id="document-language">
    <option value="All" selected="selected">All</option>
    <xsl:if test="/xml/document/language/text()">
     <xsl:for-each select="xml/document">
      <xsl:sort select="language"/>
      <xsl:if test="language/text()">
       <xsl:variable name="lastLanguage" select="language"/>
       <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::document[language=$lastLanguage])">
        <xsl:variable name="language">
         <xsl:value-of select="language"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <option value="{$language}" selected=""><xsl:copy-of select="$language" /></option>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
   </select>
  </fieldset>
        <hr class="grid-hr inner-grid"/>
   <fieldset>
   
    <legend>%%filter-by-application%%:</legend>
    <ul class="itembrowser-filter">
     <xsl:for-each select="xml/document">
      <xsl:sort select="application"/>
      <xsl:if test="application/text()">
        <xsl:variable name="lastApplication" select="application"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::document[application=$lastApplication])">
         <xsl:variable name="application">
          <xsl:value-of select="application"/>

         </xsl:variable>
         <li>
          <label>
           <input type="checkbox" class="input-big-checkbox" name="application-filter" value="{$application}"/>
           <span class="label"><xsl:copy-of select="$application" /></span>
          </label>
         </li>
        </xsl:if>
       
      </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
   </fieldset>
    </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my expected output should be as following:

```html
<hr class="grid-hr inner-grid">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Filter by Document Language:</legend>
 <label class="visuallyhidden" for="document-language">Language:</label>
 <select id="document-language">
  <option value="All" selected="selected">All</option>
  <option value="Croatian" selected="">Croatian</option>
  <option value="English" selected="">English</option>
 </select>
</fieldset>
<hr class="grid-hr inner-grid">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Filter by Application:</legend>
 <ul class="itembrowser-filter">
  <li>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-big-checkbox" name="application-filter" value="Outdoor">
    <span class="label">Outdoor</span>
   </label>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-big-checkbox" name="application-filter" value="LED]">
    <span class="label">LED</span>
   </label>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-big-checkbox" name="application-filter" value="Indoor">
    <span class="label">Indoor</span>
   </label>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="input-big-checkbox" name="application-filter" value="Signage">
    <span class="label">Signage</span>
   </label>
  </li>
 </ul>
</fieldset>
```

if anybody can help me out, then it would be great.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked [many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xslt]+split+string).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. it is rendering along with square brackets '['

These square brackets are part of your data. It seems your data provider does not understand [how to markup CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Syntax_and_interpretation). Until they learn, you must remove the extra brackets yourself, for example by replacing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="language"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(language, '[]', '')"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(language, '2', string-length(language) - 2)"/>
```

Re your second question, I suggest you do a search for "tokenize" in conjunction with XSLT 1.0. If you're unable to work it out from the previous posts, then post a separate question. Note also that your specific processor may support the EXSLT str:tokenize() extension function, thus obviating the need for a recursive named template.

I would also suggest you read up on Muenchian grouping.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. [ issue is resolved now. i will try to understand tokenizer or grouping concept.